# Find word anagrams generator

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like:

> beel beez baee beae

and I need to find the word (or its anagram) that is in common among all the words (if exist).
In this case the magic word is:

> bee

or its anagrams (ex: ebe, eeb)

My solution is:

I compare all the words between them:

```
def es(list_str):
    for i in range(len(list_str)):
        a = list_str[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(list_str)):
            b = list_str[j]
```

and then I search for the magic word:

```
def generator(a,b):
    res = []
    a = list(a)
    b = list(b)
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            res.append(i)
            b.remove(i)
    return sorted(res)
```

Actually my codes works fine, I find what I need. The problem is that with a very long list of strings it's not efficient.

Does someone have a better idea how to find this word? I can't use special libraries, it's a university homework.

Comment: Basically what you are looking for is the "intersection" (logical set operation) between two or more strings.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over a list using `range` you can just do `for elem in mylist`.

Comment: If you can return an anagram, why not find all the letters that all the words share and return any sequence of them?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misread the assignment (or I haven't misunderstood your question)? the fact that the answer is `bee` and not `ebe` and all the words contain the letters `bee` in the same order is kind of suspicious. It's a different problem to solve if you can just return an anagram of the letters they share. If there was a fifth word `ebez` would the answer still be `bee`?

Comment: let me explain better: the list of strings are anagrams of the "magic" word, plus a letter, so from "bee" I can generate "beez" or "ebez" or "beae".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to find the letters common to all words, using sets, then count the minimal number of occurences of each letter across words:

```
words = 'beel beez baee beae'.split()
common_letters = set.intersection(*(set(word) for word in words))
occurences = {letter: min(word.count(letter) for word in words) for letter in common_letters}
common_word = ''.join([letter * occurences[letter] for letter in common_letters])

print(common_word)
# bee
```

A slightly more efficient version using `collections.Counter` to avoid counting repeatedly on the same words:

```
from collections import Counter

words = 'beel beez baee beae'.split()
counts = [Counter(word) for word in words]
common_letters = set.intersection(*(set(c.keys()) for c in counts))
occurences = {letter: min(count[letter] for count in counts) for letter in common_letters}
common_word = ''.join([letter * occurences[letter] for letter in common_letters])

print(common_word)
# bee
```

Comment: you don't need to create a set of all the words, you can just do `common_letters = set(words[0])` (or any other word, doesn't have to be the first one), since if a letter doesn't appear in the first word, its min count will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a list of letters that are present in each word and order doesn't matter then count the letters in each word, find how many times it appears in whichever word it appears the fewest times, and create some word with those letters.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["beel", "beez", "baee", "beae"]

letter_counts = [Counter(word) for word in words]
shared_letters = {
    letter: min(counts[letter] for counts in letter_counts) for letter in words[0]
}
print("".join(letter * count for letter, count in shared_letters.items()))
```